# Substitute a text with long string (which varies every time) that contains special characters

Tags: regex, sed

Find and replace a text in a file. Find word is same all the time and replacing string varies all the time

I am trying a simple sed script (test.sh) to achieve this which uses a parameter(a long string with special characters):

```
sed -i "s/#####REPLACE#####/$1/g" file.txt
```

The result should replace `#####REPLACE#####` with the parameter that I pass to the script `test.sh`.

The parameter varies all the time and contains a lot of special characters (something like this):

```
"abc"/def:-/ghi$jklmno-pqrblah..blah..very..long..string
```

The command I am trying is:

```
./test.sh "abc"/def:-/ghi$jklmno-pqrblah..blah..very..long..string
```

It gives out the below message:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 25: unknown option to `s'
```

I have many files (e.g. `file1.txt`, `file2.txt`, `file3.txt`) with the same common text `#####REPLACE#####` to be replaced by the same parameter `"abc"/def:-/ghi$jklmno-pqrblah..blah..very..long..string`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed/29626460#29626460

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that you're using `/` as regex delimiter in sed and same character is part of replacement string also. Use an alternate regex delimiter in `sed`:

```
sed -i "s~#####REPLACE#####~$1~g" file.txt
```

This is assuming `~` (tilde) will not be in the replacement text. If that is the case then you can even use a *control character* such as as `^A` <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> (pressed together) as regex delimiter.

```
sed -i "s^A#####REPLACE#####^A$1^Ag" file.txt
```

**PS:** If you want to pass `&` as literal `&` in `$1` then escape it as `\&`

Comment: That will fail given various values of `$1`.

Comment: No it won't fail if `ctrl-A` is used as regex delimiter as I suggested. Only `&` needs to be provided as `\&`

Comment: Nothing magic about control-A - in addition to `&` it'll still fail if `$1` contains control-A or backslash followed by a digit or a literal newline or ends in a backslash (and more?).

Comment: i tried passing abc=$abc_abc:"$abc"/etc:"abc"/abc-abc-4.0.3 as parameter and the result is abc=:/etc:abc/abc-abc-4.0.3

Comment: You need to pass it as: `./test.sh 'abc=$abc_abc:"$abc"/etc:"abc"/abc-abc-4.0.3'` i.e. full string inside the single quote to avoid shell expansion.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to use awk instead:

```
awk -v replace="$1" '{ gsub(/#####REPLACE#####/, replace); print }' file
```

This sets an awk variable `replace` equal to the first argument passed to the function `$1`, then performs a global substitution on each line of `file`.

To overwrite the file "in-place", just use `awk ... file > tmp && mv tmp file`.

The advantage of this approach over using sed is that it doesn't matter what characters occur in the replacement string*; they will never cause a syntax error.

<sub><sup>*As pointed out in the comments, there is one character that will break things: `&`</sup></sub>

---

As you're only really interested in performing a string replacement (not a regex substitution), another option would be to use something like this:

```
awk -v replace="$1" '{
    out = ""
    while(match($0, /#####REPLACE#####/)) {
        out = out substr($0, 0, RSTART - 1) replace
        $0 = substr($0, RSTART + RLENGTH)
    }
print out $0}' file
```

This builds up a replacement string `out` using a combination of the input record `$0` and the variable `replace`.